# Is any proper subgroup is contained in normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

*Hypotheses*: Let $G$ be a infinite group that is the  product of all its  proper normal subgroups.

We have $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Can we deduce that $H$ is contained in a proper normal subgroup of $G$. If so, why?

Comment: By "product" do you mean direct product? Or the group operation, like $G=HK$ ?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 i mean the group operation